# How do i calculate the exact elapsed time

Tags: c#

The language is C#.
I've got a problem: I need to calculate the elapsed microseconds for a game which is running with a very high framerate. The problem: it's so fast that the Stopwatch always returns 0 -> under 1 millisecond. I've used google to solve my question but other people always did this:

milliseconds * 1000

which isn't gonna work since milliseconds is always 0 ...

Comment: I'd love to see that 1 million FPS game :D

Comment: Stopwatch does not have a `Miliseconds` property, it has a [`ElapsedMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, are you working with Stopwatch or DateTime using it as a stopwatch?

Comment: If your framerate is above the refresh rate of the monitor (usually about 60 Hz, or 17 ms), why not slow it down?

Comment: Instead of trying to use a `Stopwatch` to time a single frame, you could count how many frames happen in ~1 second.

Comment: @TimS. Better suggestion! I've included in my answer.

Comment: @ Aybe: it just needs to have more than 1000 frames which is very possible for small games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ticks`.

A detailed article can be found here on how to use them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

*EDIT*

Or as Tim S. suggested, you could count how many frames happen in a second.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do i know how much tick / second my computer does?

Comment: @user2997725 Read the article, you get this from the `Frequency`.

Comment: Read the article: there's a `Frequency` property.

Comment: counting frames won't always work, since the frames are between 1000 - 1800, not always the same ...